# what is the difference between Request and LoginRequest in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

what is the difference between Request and LoginRequest in laravel in these examples:

1- LoginRequest example:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming authentication request.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

2- Request example:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  ...$guards
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    throw new Exception($request);
    $guards=empty($guards)? [null] : $guards ;
    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
    }
    
    return $next($request);
}
```

I am using laravel 8.

I think my question is clear.

Comment: `LoginRequest` is a Form Request. You can use Form Requests for validation mainly.

Comment: Laravel has a request layer which you can capture the data and validate/manipulate it before it's processed by the controller.

Comment: LoginRequest  is class which is used for validation .Goto App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest there you can see it is extended from FormRequest.If you see `FormRequest`  which has few methods which help request validation.Basically FormRequest extended from `Request` class.
Only difference is FormRequest  has validation methods which help validation easier .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Request, you cannot limit your form request. But if you use Custom Form Request, you can make it flexible like what you want, you can validate, authorize, make rules, and custom error message, like LoginRequest

You can make custom request with this command

```
php artisan make:request LoginRequest
```

Or you can read on documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation